# OptionMenu suddenly closes new activity on Android 4.1.1

Tags: android, android-activity, optionmenu

Good morning, 
i've an apps with a MainActivity with optionMenu that opens another activity ( A simple About page):
All works well on Android 4.2.1 (ASUS TF700T), selecting About open the Page with About Informations.
i've this strange behaviour on my Apps with Android 4.1.1 (ICONIA A210):
When i select the optionMenu, the new activity Opens, i see the about page, but suddenly closes and return on the Main Activity.

Anyone can help me to solve this strange problem: Here is the MainActivity code:

```
    @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    MenuInflater inflater=getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    int id=item.getItemId();
    switch(id)
    {

    case R.id.MENU_2:
        Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, About.class);
        startActivity(intent2);
     break;

     default:
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Here is the simple About Code:

```
public class About extends Activity {

Button backButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.about_main);

    backButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    backButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            About.super.onBackPressed();
        }

    });


}
```

Here is menu.xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
 <item
    android:id="@+id/MENU_2"
    android:title="@string/about"
    android:orderInCategory="110"
    android:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

Anyone can help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using: `About.super.onBackPressed();`?

instead of that just use: `About.this.finish();`